# Facebook Developer Toolkit applications - deprecated template bundles

Tags: api, facebook, fdt

On this page: http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?feed I read, today:

> Facebook will deprecate template
>   bundles and their related API calls
>   December 20, 2009. Please start using
>   stream attachments with
>   stream.publish,
>   FB.Connect.streamPublish, and
>   Facebook.streamPublish instead.

Do anyone have an idea if there is a way to publish stories thru FDT not using the regisistration of template bundle?

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like it says, use streamPublish.

The Facebook Developer Toolkit v3.0 supports this through Facebook.Rest.Api.Stream.Publish

You will need the stream_publish extended permission from the user.

Comment: Yes actually it was a stupid question... I simply was using FDT in a wrong way. Version 3 is not out yet, correct? thanks

Comment: It isn't released, but there is a pretty stable version you can download from the DEV branch on Codeplex